# Flutter: Auto cursor on input text field

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

I have multiple pages, so when I enter one of them, the cursor should be automatically on input textfield, Doesnt matter how many textfields are there, I need to set on 1

**INSTEAD OF THIS:**

[image]

**THIS SHOULD BE:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextField(
          autofocus: true,
        ),
```